# I need help resolving a Runtime.ImportModuleError in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3

I am new to AWS Lambda, and I am trying to run a simple print('hello') statement in a test scenario of a Lambda function written in Python. However, I keep getting a Runtime.ImportModuleError. Here is my code:

```
import boto3

def handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    csvfile = s3.get_object(Bucket='mybucket', Key='fname.csv')
    print('hello')
```

Here is the name of my function:

[image]

And here are my Runtime settings:

[image]

My test event is configured as:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
}
```

When I hit the 'Test' button, however, I get this error message:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'dts_scrape': No module named 'dts_scrape'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Is your file at the root, or inside a folder?

Comment: It's at the root from what I can tell. There is a folder in the directory panel that says "dts_scrape - /" and the .py file is directly under that.

Comment: Try to specify your handler as `dts_scrape/dts_scrape.handler`.

Comment: That did not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out...I hadn't hit "Deploy Changes" with the correct handler name. Doing so resolved the error.